# 400 Bad Request when trying to re-index

Tags: magento2, product-reindexing

I have a Magento 2 store running with Elasticsearch 7.x and Litemage.
I’m getting the following error when trying to run an index job on Magento 2:

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index LiteMage purged tags cat_c
has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index LiteMage purged tags cat_p,BLOCK_HTML
has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:07
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Inventory index LiteMage purged tags cat_p_2791
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" >
<title> 400 Bad Request
</title></head>
<body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
        <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">400</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Bad Request
</h2>
<p>It is not a valid request!</p>
</div></div></body></html>
has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:14
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:08
Order Attributes Grid by Amasty index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Mageplaza Reward Catalog Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Mageplaza Reward Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

The issue only started once I did a "Transfer Inventory To Source" on certain products (e.g transferred inventory quantities from one source to another).

I've tried to disable litespeed_litemage module; going back to built-in cache, running the command (which doesn't give any errors) and then turning litemage back on (without success).

I'm stuck and need help.

Answer (score 0):

This landed up being that Stores -> Setting -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory Indexer Settings was not set it Asynchronous when the queue manager (rabbitmq) was installed.